# How to send PUT HTTP request to nested JSON data

Tags: json, postman, json-server

I have a JSON file in which I need to modify the properties of a nested object.

I am not able to send a PUT request using json-server in Postman.

I tried sending a PUT request to **http://localhost:3000/data/1/11** but this did not work.

I am not sure how I can access the element with id **11**

My JSON data is

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Amazon",
      "image": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "11",
          "name": "Clothes",
          "image": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG",
          "url": "http://www.google.com"
        },
        {
          "id": "12",
          "name": "Crockery",
          "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQ",
          "url": "http://www.google.com"
        },
        {
          "id": "13",
          "name": "Home Appliances",
          "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEA",
          "url": "http://www.google.com"
        }
      ]
    }  
] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the child object by `children id` using `reduce()` and `filter()`

```js
const images = {
"data": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Amazon",
        "image": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "11",
                "name": "Clothes",
                "image": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG",
                "url": "http://www.google.com"
            },
            {
                "id": "12",
                "name": "Crockery",
                "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQ",
                "url": "http://www.google.com"
            },
            {
                "id": "13",
                "name": "Home Appliances",
                "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEA",
                "url": "http://www.google.com"
            }
        ]
    }
]
};
const findImage = ((parent_id, child_id) => {
return result = images.data.reduce((r, o) => {
    const children = o.children.filter(
        ({ id }) => id === child_id && o.id === parent_id);
    if (children.length) {
        r.push(Object.assign({}, o, { children }));
    }
    return r;
}, [])[0];

})

console.log(JSON.stringify(findImage('1', '11'), null, 4));
```